# Hot Module Replacement not working with Laravel Mix and Vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant, laravel-mix, hot-module-replacement

I am trying to get Hot Module Replacement working with Laravel mix and Vagrant. My JS/CSS is compiled on the host machine and the website runs from a Vagrant box. [I have followed the instructions here](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/hot-module-replacement). I am running

```
npm run hot
```

on the host machine. When I change a JS/CSS file, the files are compiled. The correct url seems to be generated in the website. When I look in the page source I see:

```
<script src="//localhost:8080//js/min/myfile.min.js"></script>
```

This correctly returns the script (even though there are two slashes in there).. But HMR is still not working, and I get these errors in the console:

> [WDS] Disconnected!
>
> Invalid Host/Origin header

How can I get HMR working for Vagrant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `scripts` section of `package.json` disable host checks for the `hot` script

```json
"hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development 
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
--inline --hot --disable-host-check 
--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
```

Because the Laravel website is hosted on a different host and webpack dev server raises that security flag

Comment: Although, I do have a small issue with static assets - not loaded via `mix()`, because the path to those assets is now wrong...

Comment: You can do the same thing you'd do for a different domain for static assets and make a configuration URL and a helper function to load those

Comment: For example I have this global helper function in a project `function static_asset($file)
{
        return config('app.static_domain') . '/' . $file;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I had problems when running `npm run watch`/`npm run hot` on the vagrant VM. Now, I run those commands on my machine directly.

- https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/hot-module-replacement

The webserver has the IP `192.168.10.10`
and I use `"laravel-mix": "^6.0.25"`.

In `app.php`:

```
@production
    <script src="{{ asset('js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
@endproduction

@env('local')
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/js/manifest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/js/app.js"></script>
@endenv
```

And in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
```